# Get a specific key from first level in array only

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im trying to get a value from a specific key in my array. However, the key(name) exists at 2 levels, and this is not something I have control of.

I need to check the array for the value of key 'totalWeight' in a multidimensional array.

Im receiving the array and doing my check like this....

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$body = json_decode($json, true);

if($body['eventName'] == 'shippingrates.fetch') {
  $shippingWeight = $body['content']['totalWeight'];
  // other logic code here...
}
```

The rest of the code works fine, the problem is that 'totalWeight' exists at 2 levels, and I need ONLY the first level (which is the total weight of the cart, not the individual items in the cart...)

The array I receive looks like this:

```
{
  "eventName": "shippingrates.fetch",
  "mode": "Live",
  "createdOn": "2014-11-11T23:47:00.6132556Z",
  "content": {
    "items": [
      {
        "totalWeight": 1000,
        "customFields": [
          {
            "name": "Gift",
            "operation": null,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "options": "true|false",
            "required": false,
            "value": "false"
          }
        ],
        "unitPrice": 180
      },
      {
        "totalWeight": 1200,
        "customFields": [
          {
            "name": "Gift",
            "operation": null,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "options": "true|false",
            "required": false,
            "value": "false"
          }
        ],
        "unitPrice": 200
      }
    ],
    "totalWeight": 9600,
    "customFields": [
      {
        "name": "I have read and accept the   conditions of sale",
        "operation": null,
        "type": "checkbox",
        "options": "true|false",
        "required": true,
        "value": "true"
      }
    ],

    "itemsCount": 5,
    "metadata": null
  }
}
```

This is how I'm checking....

```
if($shippingWeight > '3000') {
  $rate = $shippingRatesHigh; 
} elseif($shippingWeight > '5000') {
  $rate = $shippingRatesMax;
} else {
  // default
  $rate = $shippingRatesStd;
}
```

When I have multiple items in the cart, it bases the 'totalWeight' on one of the entries inside the ['items'] array, if only one product exists then my check works...

How can I get only that 'totalWeight' inside 'content' without it travelling further into the array inside 'items'.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Your code already does EXACTLY WHAT YOU WANT.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - No unfortunately it does not. Its returning one of the 'totalWeights' in the 'items' array not the one in the 'content' array.

Comment: See my updated answer, I added the actual code I used to test before writing my answer. If you are getting one of the Weights from inside the `items` object then you are doing something differently to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a start the json data you are receiving is an object i.e. its wrapped in `{}` and not an array which would be wrapped in `[]` so why force it into an array.

If you use this idea, I think its easier to visualize.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$body = json_decode($json);

echo 'The total weight of all shipments is ' . $body->content->totalWeight;
```

If you then want to get an individual item weights or for example check that all the item weights are equal to the total weight, you could do

```
$sumOfItemRates = 0;
foreach( $body->content->items as $item) {
    $sumOfItemRates += $item->totalWeight;
}

echo 'Sum Of Individual Items Weights is ' . $sumOfItemRates;
```

I always think that objects are easier and cleaner to code than arrays.

**I tested that code, here is the full test run using PHP CLI:**

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "eventName": "shippingrates.fetch",
  "mode": "Live",
  "createdOn": "2014-11-11T23:47:00.6132556Z",
  "content": {
    "items": [
      {
        "totalWeight": 1000,
        "customFields": [
          {
            "name": "Gift",
            "operation": null,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "options": "true|false",
            "required": false,
            "value": "false"
          }
        ],
        "unitPrice": 180
      },
      {
        "totalWeight": 1200,
        "customFields": [
          {
            "name": "Gift",
            "operation": null,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "options": "true|false",
            "required": false,
            "value": "false"
          }
        ],
        "unitPrice": 200
      }
    ],
    "totalWeight": 9600,
    "customFields": [
      {
        "name": "I have read and accept the   conditions of sale",
        "operation": null,
        "type": "checkbox",
        "options": "true|false",
        "required": true,
        "value": "true"
      }
    ],

    "itemsCount": 5,
    "metadata": null
  }
}';

$body = json_decode($json);

echo 'The total weight of all shipments is ' . $body->content->totalWeight . PHP_EOL;

$sumOfItemRates = 0;
foreach( $body->content->items as $item) {
    $sumOfItemRates += $item->totalWeight;
}

echo 'Sum Of Individual Items Weights is ' . $sumOfItemRates;
```

And the output was

```
The total weight of all shipments is 9600
Sum Of Individual Items Weights is 2200
```

Which I believe is what you were asking it to do.

Comment: Thank you!!! Yes the the total weight of all shipments is what I was trying to achieve, your code update works a treat!

Comment: The only difference from your code above (not sure why as this is a bit past my understanding...) is that I needed to add 'true' to this statement...
`$body = json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: So you are still converting the `JSON OBJECT` to a `PHP Array` rather than a `PHP Object`. Thats fine, if you prefer array notation over object notation.

Comment: with my very base understanding of PHP I guess I am? I know without that attribute in json_decode then the API returns a 500 error. However, when I add the `, true` to the json_decode then it connects and works as expected... Does that mean its now a PHP array instead of an object?

Comment: Standard developer chant: _If it aint broke..... dont fix it_ i.e. if it works for you its great.